# reactjs - create react app default unit test suite not running,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I used *create-react-app* to create a new react app, but when I tried running the default unit test (using Jest and react testing library) in App.test.js, the test suite failed to run ( I have a feeling that the issue is that there's a problem with the babel configuration since create-react-app doesnt create a babel.config file, and its not able to interpret the jsx in the <App react component )

```
test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Error received:

> Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
```

And also:

> Details:

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\....\my-app\src\App.test.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (5:10):

  3 |
  4 | test('renders learn react link', () => {
> 5 |   render(<App />);
    |          ^
  6 |   const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  7 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  8 | });

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

I've already tried creating a babel.config.js file in the root of my project directory, and adding in @babel/preset-react and @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx into it, but that didnt fix the issue:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
}
```

This seems quite strange that the default unit test is failing (failing to run) straight away, so there must be something that's wrong with my configuration. If anyone could be of help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are running the test through `npm/yarn run test`?

Comment: I just tried running 'npm run test' and the test passed successfully that way. 
Before I was running the test by clicking 'run' (where it says 'Run | Debug' just above the unit test in vsCode), so Im not too sure why its failing when I do that, but it passes when I use the 'npm run test' command.

Comment: `npm run test` will run `react-scripts test` which in turn has a lot of webpack and other configuration files that it injects. When you try to run the test manually, it runs without that configuration.

Comment: If you are interested in seeing the configuration that's used, you can run `npm run eject` to eject from cra and expose all the configuration it does under the hood. It's irreversible though, so backup before you do if there is anything of worth in the project.